# Proper way of sharing data and methods in Java

Tags: java, oop, class

So I'm finally starting learn efficient programming (Used to use one class for everything), and this new game I'm making has the following classes so far:

- GameDriver
- Map
- Block
- Player

And as of right now, Map creates an ArrayList of Block objects, and the GameDriver creates a Map object and a Player object, now that's all working perfectly fine and good. But now I ran into a problem.

I added a method to Player called checkLand() and GameDriver calls that method to check if the player can step on a certain spot, but for the method to be able to check it, it needs access to the map object that the GameDriver is using so I tried this:

```
public class Player(){
    GameDriver gameDriver = new GameDriver();
    ...more declarations    

    public boolean checkLand(int xCord, int yCord){
        if (gameDriver.map.world.get(gameDriver.map.getByCords(xCord,yCord)).type == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        } 

    }
```

But obviously it doesn't work, but I wanted to show you guys so you could get an understanding of what I want it to do, should I just have the checkLand method in GameDriver? I want to know the best way please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Player` object is being created by the `GameDriver` object, you should be able to access the `Player` object within your `GameDriver` class. Also, you said that the `Map` object is also being created within your `GameDriver` class, so that is also available.

What you could do would be to have a method in your `Player` class which takes a `Map` object as parameter and does the logic you need.

This will allow your `GameDriver` object to call an object which it has (`Player`) and pass it another object it also has (`Map`).

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you so much! Does it sound like I'm coding this in a pretty efficient manner or is a lot of work needed?

Comment: @JeremySayers: I can't quite say, I do not know what exactly you are trying to do it and how. That being said, I would recommend you take a look at **Design Patterns**, a useful website available [here](http://oodesign.com/). These patterns, most of the time make you application design cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, I wish I understood more of what that site was talking about, but that just means I have more learning to do :)

Comment: @JeremySayers: There are entire books devoted to the subject, so it is expected to miss out on some things.